# fancybox data - (not form) - submit to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox-2

I have a form the user fills in, then can submit the form or preview the data.  If the user chooses to preview the data, I assemble it into a nicer-looking page (rather than just showing the form again).  From here they can press submit or go back to the form.  Thanks to @JFK and @jerdiggity on this forum, I have a great looking preview.  Now when I press submit from the preview iframe I am trying to call a function with a file called sendMessageclass.php.   In my preview pane I have these 2 buttons at the end:

```
    <a class="submit btn login-submit" name="saveData" href="javascript:;">Submit</a>
    <a class="closeFB btn login-submit" href="javascript:;">Back to Edit</a>
```

At the beginning of the preview.php file I have the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#saveData').live('click', function() {
          $.post('classes/sendMessage.class.php?\__construct');
    return false;
    });
```

The __construct function begins with:

```
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
         foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)   
          .........
```

it continues to validate the fields, then submit them to the db.  I know this part works because when I submit the form (without doing a preview), the data is inserted into the db fine. 
My error in Firebug when I press submit is:

```
 TypeError: e[h] is not a function
```

I've also tried adding the line below in sendMessageclass.php to make sure it's the submit button being pressed, not the preview button:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Any ideas how I can get sendMessageclass.php to get called when I press the submit button from the preview.php file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try either of these options :

1). Replace the `name` attribute of your html

```
<a class="submit btn login-submit" name="saveData" href="javascript:;">
```

by the `id` attribute like

```
<a class="submit btn login-submit" id="saveData" href="javascript:;">
```

... you can't refer to elements with `name` attribute using the selector `#saveData`

Check this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D9D9u/)** and you will see that clicking on the link with `name="nameData"` returns nothing.

2). Replace your current script selector and format

```
$('#saveData').live("click", function(){ ... })
```

... to

```
$("body").on("click", "a[name=saveData]", function(){ ... })
```

... without changing the html and keeping the `name` attribute.

**Notice** that `.live()` is deprecated so we are using `.on()` in its delegated form (requires jQuery 1.7+ though)

Also notice that you could change the `body` element by the *selector* of the parent container of `a[name=saveData]`

Comment: I tried both options and neither worked. I still get the error:
       `code` TypeError: e[h] is not a function `code`

It is registering the "click" as I log that to the console.

Comment: On further review, turns out I need to load jquery again in the fancybox.  I am still unable to get the data to submit to the db however; I press submit, and I am returned to the parent page, but no data is sent to the db.  The preview works great, and the data displays.  I have nothing in the preview file except grabbing the POST data and echoing it to display the data. Here is the pertinent part of the form.php:

Comment: `$('.preview').on("click", function (e) {  
       ........
        afterShow: function(){  
         $(".submit, .closeFB").on("click", function(event){    
          if( $(event.target).is(".submit") ){  
           alert("submit"); // works, I get the alert                 
     $("#message_form").submit(); // submit the actual form  
          }
        $.fancybox.close(); //close fancybox   
        }); // on click  `

                          .... close up all parens